# How to store many files that are updated frequently in a centralised location that can be accessed live

Tags: python, database, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, storage

I have many server instances in google cloud that are running all day collecting data from various edge devices. I have around a 100 servers each collecting from around 50 devices.

The data for each source is updated in different frequencies, some could be per second, some could be per minute, 5 minute, half hourly, hourly, 4 hourly, half day, up to daily.

The data is usually 2 columns, date + time in one column and the datapoint in the other, so it could be temperature data, or soil moisture data, wind direction that kind of thing.

Right now, each server collects the data into python pandas data frames, and updates them live, then at the end of the day, they're updated or saved into csv files (2 column csv files). Each device that collects data has its own csv file. I don't update them into one big dataframe because there will be a lot of empty spaces in the because of the difference in update frequencies.

It could look like this:

```
DateTime              Device-19-Location-27-Temperature
01-June-2020 1:00p.m. 21.4
01-June-2020 1:01p.m. 21.5
....
```

When I need to access the data, I have to SSH into the servers one by one and download the files into my computer and work with the data after that.

My knowledge of databases close to none so I have been doing it this way.

My first question is, is storing them in separate csv files the best way? I thought of doing this because of the different update frequencies.

And my second question is, is there a centralised location or database on google cloud or elsewhere where I can store all these files, access them, update them using some kind of python API so that I only have to access a single location to get all my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description I think that a good option for you could be a NoSQL database, you could check these options: [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore) or [Firebase Realtime Database](http://ttps://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/).

With regard to your other questions about store files, access them, update them using some kind of python API. On GCP an option could be [Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage). You can store your files there, download them to work with them and update the version when you finish to work with them using [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).This option is not to work with the files directly on the buckets(on the fly).